# formatting excel cell

Tags: excel, formatting

I am in trouble. I have thousands of customer data having name, address, zip. I have data in excel and the problem is in zip code. The Zip should be 5 character long and if it is not, we have to add zero at front to make equal to five character. Since there are thousands of data and it is not feasible to change it one by one, can somebody suggest me to format the column of zip so that it could be 5 character long.

Comment: Why do you need 5 digits with leading zeros?  What are you going to do with the data? (i.e. Is this excel file the source going to some other destination like a database?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the custom format and use the type : 00000

Answer (score 2):

Write the following formula in front of that zip column:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>5,"Invalid",RIGHT("00000" & A1,5))
```

Just replace the cell reference name A1 to the first cell of zip code column and then drag the cell down. Now all those zip codes that are less than five characters will be filled with leading zeros. Also It will show Invalid in cells which have a zip code of more than 5 characters length.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this formula to the cell values, i.e. for `A1` in this example:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000#")
```

Copy/paste the formatted values (as text) into the desired column if you need them in a specific column.

Answer (score 1):

Simply mark the whole column. 
Than right click to get into the "format cells" settings. 
There you go to "special format" and there you should mark "ZipCode". 
[Here](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-18887739/Unbenannt.png.html) is a picture of the options. It is in german, so I hope you will find it anyway ;)

Comment: but next time it automatically removes the zero again when I opened in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Quick macro to convert the range to Text format, and append leading zeros if the cell is less than 5 characters.

```
Sub AddLeadingZeros()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A1:A10") '<modify as needed, the cells containing ZIP'
Dim cl As Range


rng.NumberFormat = "@"
For Each cl In rng

    If Len(cl.Value) < 5 Then
        Do

            cl.Value = "0" & cl.Value

        Loop While Len(cl.Value) < 5
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for you effort, but I have never used macro. have to learn that first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. select your column
2. Format-> cell
3. Special format-> zip code

make sure you save the changes... it shouldn't remove zero...

or try a "user defined" format... but I never tried it.